# Stuck at Welcome screen to install Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, 32-bit

After starting the virtual machine, it freezes at this point and won't start installing Ubuntu. There's no pop-up, welcome screen or whatsoever.
I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS i386

[image]

UPDATE: So i was following this guide: https://linus.nci.nih.gov/bdge/installUbuntu.html until I start the virtual machine. I should be seeing a welcome screen but I didn't. No error message or warning.
I don't think it is the duplicate of How to install Ubuntu on VirtualBox? thread.
Memory I gave: 1024 mb
I also followed nathanwww's solution but got the same result.

Ok... So now I am confused. If I am trying to run Ubuntu on virtual box. Do I need a CD or USB to boot it?

Comment: How much memory did you give to the machine?

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: That guide looks alright and I'm **voting to reopen** the question since now we have a good idea what you did. From where did you get Ubuntu installer ISO? Could you please check [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](/q/162075/175814) and particularly section 1 of [the top answer](/a/162076/175814) and see if they help? They would be my next go-to diagnosis steps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mount the Ubuntu iso to a virtual drive location.

When the virtual machine starts, it may ask to specify the optical drive (or virtual optical drive) to install/boot from.

Otherwise, you can press / hold down F12 right after the virtual machine starts, allowing you to manually select several options. First, go to Devices, and make sure that the (real or virtual) optical drive containing the iso is selected. Then, select the option to boot from CD.

This should get you to screen which will allow you to proceed with installation.